# Facebook PHP Graph SDK performance issue

Tags: php, performance, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm currently using Facebook PHP SDK v5 for a simple task: converting a Javascript short-lived user token to a long lived one and returning it.

The issue I'm having is that the requests seem to take a very long time when issued from the SDK compared to Postman or the Graph API explorer.

In order to benchmark it I have used some profiling calls, I'm measuring both the high level execution times and the lowest level possible (wrapping the cURL call) to make sure the issue is not related to additional PHP overhead.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $options['app_id'],
  'app_secret' => $options['app_secret'],
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
$prev = performanceLog($prev, 'FBInit');
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    die(500);

} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    die(500);
}
$prev = performanceLog($prev, 'GetToken');
if (!isset($accessToken)) {
    if ($helper->getError())
    {
        die(var_dump($helper->getError()));
    } else {
        die(500);
    }
}
else
{
    // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
    $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);

    // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId($options['app_id']);
    // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();
    $prev = performanceLog($prev, 'Validation');
    if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        try {
            $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            die(var_dump($e));
        }
    }
    $prev = performanceLog($prev, 'GetLong');
    echo $accessToken->getValue();
    $prev = performanceLog($prev, 'EchoGetValue');
}
```

Which is fairly standard, the profiling times I get are:

```
Init : 0.15900301933289


FBInit : 0.0040819644927979


GetToken : 1.5706379413605
Of which Request : 1.566477060318


Validation : 1.5675730705261
Of which Request : 1.5646359920502


GetLong : 0.56497001647949
Of which Request : 0.56240797042847

EchoGetValue : 4.0531158447266E-6
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there some other solution besided caching?
Keep in mind the times I get are really variable: they go from 3 seconds to around 12, sometimes it even times out.

Thanks